# Is there a non-trigger way of cascading nullable columns to referencing tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, cascade, postgresql-9.6

Foreign constraints are ignored for rows where parts of the foreign key are `null`. That also means that changes made to a nullable column are not propagated to the child tables.

Compare https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e666862f83177715b45eb04f0b0221e1

Is there any non-trigger way of setting up a propagation of nullable columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see the issue here.  A foreign key with a `NULL` value has no relationship to the parent table.  So `watcher_3` is linked through `foo_w__foo_id_foo_prop__fk`, but not `foo_w__foo_id_foo_prop_foo_target`.

So, there is no link for propagation to update the target, because there is not a proper foreign key relationship.

The one way you can do what you want is to introduce a "fake" `NULL` value, as in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4f4903d6e385f09997903cf7b7c01859) example.

That said, your example reminds me of why I avoid cascading constraints.